# disable event onbeforeunload for 1 event button only

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, onbeforeunload

I use JavaScript function beforeunload to display a modal during the loading of the application. 
Code in my master page:

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
            var modal = document.createElement("div");
            modal.className = "modal-backdrop fade in"
            modal.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            var loader = document.createElement("div");
            loader.className = "loader"
            loader.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></i><br/><br/>Veuillez patienter...<br/>';
            document.body.appendChild(modal);
            document.body.appendChild(loader);
            return null;
        });
    </script>
```

It works well except for a button event that generates an excel file. The end of the loading is not detected so the modal does not close.

For information I give the end of c# code of the button event:

```
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

I tried to call this function in my button event but it doesn't work :

```
function stopNavigate() {

        window.onbeforeunload = null;

    }
```

How can I disable the beforeunload for this button only ?

Comment: Why are you adding an hour glass when a user choose to close the tab/window?

Comment: I add an hour glass when the browser is loading not when a user choose to close th window

Comment: ???...the `beforeunload` fires upon close, not load, so with that your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the listener function into a standalone function that can be referenced elsewhere, so it's not anonymous. Then, you can remove it using `removeEventListener` later. (Assigning `null` to an `on*` property will only remove a listener that was attached using the same `on*` property)

```
function unloadHandler (e) {
  var modal = document.createElement("div");
  modal.className = "modal-backdrop fade in"
  modal.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  var loader = document.createElement("div");
  loader.className = "loader"
  loader.innerHTML = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></i><br/><br/>Veuillez patienter...<br/>';
  document.body.appendChild(modal);
  document.body.appendChild(loader);
  return null;
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadHandler);

// ...

function stopNavigate() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', unloadHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !